# how to launch an app from another app in android

Tags: android, launch

I am developing an app in which i want to launch any application installed on my device. I have tried the following code.

```
Button bClock = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
String app="com.whatsapp";
bClock.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    PackageManager managerclock = getPackageManager();
    i = managerclock.getLaunchIntentForPackage(app);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    startActivity(i);
  }
});
```

It shows error:

> Cannot refer to a non-final variable app inside an inner class defined
>   in a different method

But if I directly use "com.whatsapp" instead of storing in String, it is working. Help me to solve this issue

Comment: issue with final variable. just declare the string app as global and refer in your button click

Comment: what do you mean by " refer in your button click" can you explain it in detail. I am new to android

Comment: check shree krishna's answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Launch an application from another application on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/launch-an-application-from-another-application-on-android)

Answer (score 3):

For your code correction please make `String app="com.whatsapp";` a final variable or you can use package name directly like following

You should use the function of the package manager.

```
Context ctx=this; // or you can replace **'this'** with your **ActivityName.this**
try {
Intent i = ctx.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.whatsapp");
ctx.startActivity(i);
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

Comment: thanks it works. But in my case, the application has to be chosen from the spinner . So I have used String to strore the package name

Answer (score 1):

If so then make it final

```
final String app="com.whatsapp";
```

**OR**

Declare it as global variable of class like

```
public class MyClass {

String app="com.whatsapp";

//Other methods
}
```